# Most Performant Way to Store Non-Standard Data

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

### Background

I have to store information about a set of products. This information is going to be pulled out via PHP onto a website, possibly in conjunction with WordPress, possibly using raw PHP. The problem is that these products have inconsistent attributes. Example:

Product A

- Width => 6"
- Height => 5"
- Weight => 2 lb
- Color => Black

Product B

- Weight => 3lb
- Manufacturer => Microsoft
- Date => 2015-02-01

The simple answer is a single table in SQL, with an ever expanding number of columns, most of them empty, to cover every possible attribute. I don't think that is the way to go though, given the number of possible attributes and the need for extensibility.

---

### Idea 1

One thought I have is to set up one table, with each row being a product, and having an ID. A second table will have every row be an attribute, linked by the product ID.

**Table 1**

```
Product | ID
Phone   | 0001
Table   | 0002
```

**Table 2**

```
Product ID | ID   | Attribute Label | Attribute Value
0001       | 0001 | Height          | 2"
0001       | 0002 | Width           | 3"
0001       | 0003 | Weight          | 2lb
0002       | 0004 | Company         | Apple
0002       | 0005 | Color           | Black
0002       | 0006 | Weight          | 2lb
```

The problem I see with this is that table 2 gets massive in number of rows.

---

### Idea 2

Nested Array, stored Somehow

**Table**

```
Product | Attributes | ID
Phone   | ARRAY      | 0001
Table   | ARRAY      | 0002
```

Where I have the `ARRAY` be an array of key-value pairs. Serialized maybe, and stored? I could have an unlimited set of key-value pairs I would think.

---

## My Question

What is the most performant way to achieve storing this sort of data? Are there best practices? Is there a different type of database entirely? I've heard the phrase JSON, could it be useful here?

Comment: The optimal way to store data is determined by how the data is being used.  Your question does not include any such relevant information.

Comment: Added information about usage.

Comment: First, we must stop using the word "performant". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How about product categories? That helps to normalize things.

Comment: That is one thing I'm considering. A set of categories that can can at least partly normalize. But with the products I'm working with, even products in the same category aren't fully normal.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is what you're looking for, but only if you don't ever want to search or sort your database by one of these "extra" attributes. The usage is  extremely simple, there are built-in [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) PHP functions. json_encode converts structural data (eg your array of parameters) into string representation, which then may be saved in MySQL's TEXT column. If you're using postgres, there are also JSON and JSONB types. json decode does exactly opposite thing and converts text back to array of parameters.

JSON **serialization** gives you definitely the highest possible performance in your scenario.

If search or sort by these attributes is a requirement, then attribute-table may better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not** need to query/search the data systematically, it is possible to use JSON json_encode() or PHP serialize() to store the data.

If you **do** need to query/search the data systematically, I personally prefer key/value pairs for non-standard stored in the database. I recommend using two tables. For example:

```
TABLE PRODUCTS:

ID    | ProductName    | Category | Price  | ...
------+----------------+----------+--------+----
12345 | Toothbrush     | Misc.    |   2.99 | ...
12115 | MS Windows DVD | Software |  99.00 | ...
76354 | AMD FX-8350    | CPUs     | 189.00 | ...

TABLE PRODUCTSPECS:

ID   | ProductID | KeyName   | Value
-----+-----------+-----------+-------
0001 |     12345 | Width     | 6"
0001 |     12345 | Height    | 8"
0002 |     12115 | Depth     | 6"
0003 |     12115 | Mfg.      | Microsoft
0004 |     76354 | Socket    | AM3+
```

You could take it further and use two 'Key' columns, one for a short form, and one for a descriptive form, though this really depends on your application.

ID would be unique to each row, and preferably set to auto_increment. ProductID should use a constraint, referencing the ID of your products table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be "happier" with a document-base database like e.g. [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/).
That's not that different from the JSON solutions proposed; e.g. the documentation says

> The document structure in MongoDB are BSON objects with support for the full range of BSON types; however, BSON documents are conceptually, similar to JSON objects, and have the following structure:

but you won't lose the ability to directly search the database for documents 
with certain properties.

Answer (score 0):

The type of model you're contemplating is called the [Entity-Attribute-Value Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and it's fairly common for the situation you're describing.  I wouldn't use JSON here, it just adds a layer of complexity when storing or retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for common properties of products:

```
products (product_id PK, product_name)
```

And tables for related sets of optional properties:

```
weights (product_id PK/FK, weight)
sizes (product_id PK/FK, width, height)
colors (product_id PK/FK, color)
manufactured (product_id PK/FK, company_id FK, date)
```

EAV schemas make it difficult to impose integrity or to query, and get worse with the number of attributes.  Do some research before you buy into this.